# How to install postcss with Angular2 CLI the right way

Tags: angular, webpack, postcss

just learning Angular2 and I want to install postcss. I found several older posts that try to explain how to install postcss on Angular2. All of them are obsolete since none of them takes into account that there is no `angular-cli-build.js` anymore since Angular2 CLI is using webpack now. I installed the loader `npm install postcss-loader --save-dev` and created the config file `postcss.config.js` as described in the [npm repo](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-loader) but whats next? Do I need to add it to `angular-cli.json`? If so - how? Any help appreciated! Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Angular CLI is using webpack, but it is not allow to config and It seem that there is no plan to allow developer to config it. ( Ref: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1656#issuecomment-249921747 )

However, there is a work around solution mentioned in this comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1512#issuecomment-254262959

Comment: Update: you are now able to eject the project from Angular CLI to a normal webpack project (Ref: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/eject.md )